# How to add months to a date in Botostrap DateTimePicker upon clicking a button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

My `DatePicker` has a date that I am loading from the database. However, upon clicking a button, I want to add 6 months to the date that was there in the `DatePicker` before clicking the button. How can I do that?

I am doing this in the following way, but I am getting the following errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: NewDate is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

```
function NewDate() {
    var newDate = $("#selectedDate").val(@Model.SelectedDate.AddMonths(6)));
    $("#selectedDate").datepicker('setDate',newDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 function NewDate() {
  var dt = "@Model.SelectedDate.AddMonths(6).ToShortDateString()";
  var newDate = $("#selectedDate").val(dt);
  $("#selectedDate").datepicker('setDate', newDate);
 }
  
</script>
```